# Place iframe contents after fieldset

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css

I have an iframe:

```
<iframe src='myurl.php' frameborder='0' width='500' height='500' ></iframe>
```

I need to place its contents right below a `<fieldset></fieldset>` element.

How can I do that using jquery/javascript?

I am working with dynamic content so is not that easy as to put the iframe right below the fieldset.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Have you tried putting that?

Comment: Check my answer but first please consider to update you question with more accurate problem/code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First as dudzio said, use it simple like this:

`<fieldset></fieldset>
<iframe src='myurl.php' frameborder='0' width='500' height='500'></iframe>`

If you have another problems and you don't tell us corectly you can use:
CSS, sample: **position:absolute;top:X px;** for iframe,

If your fieldset is not visible it may be **z-index** lower than another element on page.

We need the entire page to check why fieldset is below iframe... A lot of causes can be responsible for this. Please update you question!

Answer (score 0):

I supose you want a fieldset at top of the iframe. Put them into consecutive div's.

But this doesn't use javascript/jquery just plain HTML tags.

Answer (score -2):

```
<fieldset></fieldset>
<iframe src='myurl.php' frameborder='0' width='500' height='500'></iframe>
```

It should be that simple. If it's not - check CSS code, especially float: left/right or position:absolute for fieldset element.

And try to avoid using iframes it can make a lot of troubles. Starting with CSS styling problems, ending with security issues, for example with https protocol.

Comment: Don't now why I have negative points for that. The first part is answering 100% of question.